# How can I change the column size in a `DataGridView`?

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I change the column size in a `DataGridView`?

```
datagridview1.Columns[1].Width = 100;
```

I tried this code, but it doesn't work, because the column in the picture doesn't have a number.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must use [DataGridView.RowHeadersWidth Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheaderswidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
datagridview1.RowHeadersWidth = 100;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this property:

```
datagridview1.RowHeadersWidth = 100;
```

Comment: Your answer seems kind of late.